# open graph in website and iframe - make twitter, fb read only the one from iframe

Tags: jquery, facebook, iframe

I got clients, which have an iframe on theirs website, where my products are shown. Each product has its individual og:image and twitter:image meta tag and a twitter/fb share button.

Unfortunately twitter and facebook just read the meta tags of the clients website and not the once in the iframe, so the picuters and descriptions posted are wrong. Also there is a case where one customer has his own og and twitter meta tags, in this case twitter/fb are reading the customers og meta tags.

The solution I am searching, is that if someone clicks the share button, which is in the iframe, twitter and fb get the open graph meta tags informations from the iframe.

Is this possible and with what kind of technology, can I say to twitter/fb to fetch my og meta tags from the iframe and not the ones from the top site. I have seen examples how to read the meta tags in the iframe using jquery, but how to hand it over to twitter and fb? So that on a page with containing my iframe, the metatags inside the iframe are read athorwise from the main website.

Thank you for reading my question and hopefully someone has a good idea.

Comment: You can’t use JavaScript for this – the scrapers that FB and twitter use to read this data do not execute any JavaScript. You can only achieve this by sharing the URL that is displayed inside the iframe, and not the URL of the “outer” page around it. You could then use JavaScript inside of your iframe, to direct human visitors that arrive on that URL after following a link from FB/twitter back to the “outer” page. (That will of course only work if you use that specific iframe URL only in one specific “outer” page, and not on multiple pages.)

Comment: Hi CBroe, you are right I tried the redirect which led to a recursion. So I am trying with easyXDM now, as the client also has to get the right metatags out of the iframe. I realized though, that the clients site is always on the same url, while only inside the iframe the url changes when looking for a product. So the next problem occures, when does the main site know when i am on a product page inside the iframe, is there somthing needed like a heartbeat, where the parent site waits for a message from the iframe. I have no idea yet about easyXDM, is there maybe someone that can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @CBroe mentions in their comment: OpenGraph `<meta>` tags need to be added to the document by the web server that serves it, and not by javascript.

If your website is a single document on the outside, but all navigational activity happens inside an iframe, you are probably upsetting most of your users, and you make it nearly impossible for anyone to link to specific content.

That being said, that is orthogonal to how you can make the share button work properly, when you place it on the pages inside the iframe. You can configure the share button for each inner document's URL, i.e. for the URL shown of what's currently shown in the iframe. That document could contain all the required OpenGraph `<meta>` data.
But this also means that people clicking on the shared link resulting from this will be directed to the inner document, without the iframe wrapped around it.

You can resolve this by using javascript to redirect anyone back to your index document (which renders the iframe with the actual content), and hope that can also cause that index document to subsequently load the right content in the iframe. This idea is arguably not great, because it will trigger a bunch of redirects and it depends on Javascript to work.

A different approach would be to start using a fragment beginning with `#!`. Inside the fragment you could encode what content is currently show inside the index document's iframe.
If you add JavaScript to the index document that recognizes the current fragment and then loads the corresponding content into the iframe, you would be serving the right content to your users without redirects. Additionally, using URLs with such a fragment works with the Facebook scraper, as it will follow the [`_escaped_fragment_` specification](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification#bidirectional-between--url-to-_escaped_fragment_-url).

Comment: Like #derabbink mentioned, now in the iframe I generate a url with parameters to the chosen product site, example client.com/?iframeId=id&productId=id. Twitter or fb fetches the link. I use CORS Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*  in the iframe to communicate with parent website. The clients website has  some Javascript, that creates the meta tags on the fly, which it reads out of the iframe and places them inside the parent site. Because the script is doing that only when it .find("meta[property^='og:']"); which is called by a callback function with ajax. So now the above link serves those og tags